# Event Log ID 7039, then the service is set to running and stopped state. But OnStart is never called

Tags: c#, windows, service, event-log

I have a windows service created with the microsoft example.

```
public MyService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.eventLog1 = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.eventLog1)).BeginInit();
        // 
        // eventLog1
        // 
        this.eventLog1.Log = "Application";
        this.eventLog1.Source = "MyService";
        // 
        // MyService
        // 
        this.CanHandlePowerEvent = true;
        this.CanHandleSessionChangeEvent = true;
        this.CanShutdown = true;
        this.ServiceName = "MyService";
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.eventLog1)).EndInit();

    }

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {

            eventLog1.WriteEntry("Initializing...");

            Init();
            ServiceConfig.Settings.Initialize("MyService");
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("Starting...");

            //do some stuff

            eventLog1.WriteEntry("Started");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("Error:" + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            base.OnStart(args);
        }
    }
```

This windows service is configured to start automatically when windows starts.
Everything is working fine almost everywhere and almost always, but it happens that rarely this service doesn't start when OS starts.
In these cases I always find the same situation on event log.
On the Application log I have nothing and on the System log I have first the event ID 7039, than the event ID 7036 with "MyService is in running status" and at the same time, but after, another event ID 7036 with "MyService is stopped".

Instead, when everything works fine, I have only "MyService is in running status" on System Log with a time that come after all the Application's log I write and that you can see in the code.

So, my opinion is that in thoose cases it doesn't work, the service is never started by the Service Control Manager, the OnStart method is not called.
So it could be the OS's fault.
What's your opinions?
Thanks!

Comment: Is Startup set to `Automatic (Delayed Start)`?

Comment: No, is Automatic only.

Comment: You might try configuring the service to be dependent on the Windows Event Log service.  I wouldn't *expect* that to be necessary, but it may be worth checking.  You could also have your service write a plain text log file at various points, e.g., the main() function, InitializeComponent(), in OnStart() before doing anything else, etc., and see if that gives you any clue to where the failure is happening.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I'll do them and I'll get back as soon as I'll have a feedback.